# Hello i want to make my app online using 000webhost but im getting error. below is my code

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
 public static final String BASE_URL = "http://kanzen.000webhostapp.com/";

 public static final String API_TOKEN_URL = "http://kanzen.000webhostapp.com/braintree/main.php";
```

Here's the link I'm now using on my Common.java

Before it was working fine using this.

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost/";

 public static final String API_TOKEN_URL = "http://localhost/braintree/main.php";

Here's where i'm getting the error which is my MainActivity.java

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            AccountKitLoginResult  result = data.getParcelableExtra(AccountKitLoginResult.RESULT_KEY);

            if (result.getError() != null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+result.getError().getErrorType().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (result.wasCancelled())
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
                {
                    if (result.getAccessToken() != null) {
                        final android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = new SpotsDialog(MainActivity.this);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Processing... Please Wait....");

                        AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(final Account account) {

                                mService.checkUserExists(account.getPhoneNumber().toString())
                                        .enqueue(new Callback<CheckUserResponse>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onResponse(Call<CheckUserResponse> call, Response<CheckUserResponse> response) {
                                                CheckUserResponse userResponse = response.body();
                                                if (userResponse.isExists())
                                                {
                                                    mService.getUserInformation(account.getPhoneNumber().toString())
                                                            .enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

                                                                    alertDialog.dismiss();

                                                                    Common.currentUser = response.body();

                                                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                                                                    finish();
                                                                }

                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                                                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                }
                                                else
                                                    {
                                                        alertDialog.dismiss();

                                                        showRegisterDialog(account.getPhoneNumber().toString());
                                                    }
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(Call<CheckUserResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        });
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(AccountKitError accountKitError) {
                                Log.d("ERROR",accountKitError.getErrorType().getMessage());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Here's the error I'm getting when running the app

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.motasemx.itsproject, PID: 17303
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.motasemx.itsproject.Model.CheckUserResponse.isExists()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.motasemx.itsproject.MainActivity$4$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:201)
                      at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6802)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

Comment: i think its not the same case

Comment: you can prevent the crash alike: `if (userResponse != null && userResponse.isExists())` - while the actual problem may be, that the response has no body.

Comment: i have else statement that generates registration if userResponse does not exist

Comment: this does not matter, because you cannot check anything, while getting no response.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are getting null pointer exception because returned response from your server is null and you are trying to access a null object

```
 mService.checkUserExists(account.getPhoneNumber().toString())
                                    .enqueue(new Callback<CheckUserResponse>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(Call<CheckUserResponse> call, Response<CheckUserResponse> response) {
                                            CheckUserResponse userResponse = response.body();
                                            //userResponse is null
                                            if (userResponse.isExists())
                                            {

                                            }
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(Call<CheckUserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                                        }
                                    });
```

Comment: are you saying that my app is not connecting to my database? can you please tell me what should i do, its the first time that i have made an app using php

Comment: may be cannot connect to your server or your database check your provided url is correct and test it on a browser to see returned response

Comment: the url is correct and working fine when i try it on browser

Comment: tried debugging it and it gave me this
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Internal Server Error, url=http://kanzen.000webhostapp.com/checkuser.php}

Comment: error code 500 is for your app cannot connect to server

Comment: what should i do sir? please tell me